# Is generating Javascript Code and HTML Tags from HTMLHelper a Bad Practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

maybe this is a stupid question, but i have seen many Tuts that build JavaScript ode and HTML Tags from an HTML Helper Extension Method like creating a Jquery Menu or Tree, it looks so neat and saves cluttering in View and encourage re usability.

but i am wondering that because this code is generated on Server Side  will it be slower than writing the code directly  in the View ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not. Even the MVC Framework has HTML Helper(s) that do this. Why would it be?

Comment: hey dude, 
second reply to me in a very short time :)
thanks a lot again.

i am new to MVC and was just trying to make sure, when you come from Web forms a lot of things are confusing :)